# Problems with resizing png's

Tags: php, resize, png

I'm having a problem resizing my minecraft skins with this script.
When I test it on my localhost, everything works 100% fine, but when I upload it my server, it only displays a resized transparent image, with no content.
Here's the script:

```
<?php
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
 }

// File and new size
$fil = clean($_GET['skin']);

 header('Content-type: image/png');
//$myimage = resizeImage('filename', 'newwidthmax', 'newheightmax');

function resizeImage($filename, $newwidth, $newheight){
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$transparent = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 200, 255, 200);
imagefill($thumb, 0, 0, $transparent);
imagecolortransparent($thumb, $transparent);

$source = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

return imagepng($thumb);
}

$myimage = resizeImage($fil, '640', '320');
print $myimage;

?>
```

You can see the output here: [link](http://pzyko.net/skins/newrez.php?skin=http://www.pzyko.net/skins/skins/13498263321749529476.steve.png)

Comment: Is `$fil` actually filled when you call `resizeImage()` with it? Your `clean()` function takes it through `mysql_real_escape_string()` which will fail if there's no active mysql connection around. It should be spitting out E_WARNINGs for you if you set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` up on top.

Comment: You might also want to check that your localhost and server are running the same versions of GD, and more importantly that `$filename` is readable, and that `imagecreatefrompng()` is successful.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string requires an already opened connection to mysql. It will use the last connection opened, if non exists it will return false. Perhaps that's where you are missing your data.

Comment: I tried to remove the function but it didn't work. I also tried to connect to a database at the top of the script, but it didn't work either :S